# Detectar movimiento scroll de un select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo este codigo de ejemplo:

```
</head>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contenido2').scroll(function(){
            var windowHeight = $('#contenido2').scrollTop();
            console.log(windowHeight);
            });
});
</script>
<body>  

<div id="contenido">

  <select id="contenido2">
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
  </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Como puedo detectar el movimiento del scroll de select?, si el scroll es el de pagina, no hay problema pero si es el del select no hay manera de que detecta nada.

Comment: Lamentablemente no existe un evento scroll que se lance en el elemento nativo `<select>`, tendrías que usar algún componente que simule ser un select

Answer (score 2):

No puedes detectar este evento desde navegador, dado que se renderiza en el lado del cliente. Pero no estas perdido, prueba a usar [select2](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage) que si te permite manejar estos eventos.

Te pongo un ejemplo de como quedaria el select despues de usar la libreria select2.

```
<span class="select2-results">
<ul class="select2-results__options" role="tree" id="select2-x4am-results" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
    <li class="select2-results__option" role="group" aria-label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
        <strong class="select2-results__group">Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone</strong>
        <ul class="select2-results__options select2-results__options--nested">
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-wabm-AK" role="treeitem" aria-selected="true">Alaska</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted" id="select2-x4am-result-s7im-HI" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Hawaii</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="select2-results__option" role="group" aria-label="Pacific Time Zone">
        <strong class="select2-results__group">Pacific Time Zone</strong>
        <ul class="select2-results__options select2-results__options--nested">
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-uihp-CA" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">California</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-h7ix-NV" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Nevada</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-jl5v-OR" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Oregon</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-2e8j-WA" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Washington</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="select2-results__option" role="group" aria-label="Mountain Time Zone">
        <strong class="select2-results__group">Mountain Time Zone</strong>
        <ul class="select2-results__options select2-results__options--nested">
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-upe1-AZ" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Arizona</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-w72c-CO" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Colorado</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-q4b6-ID" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Idaho</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-anl2-MT" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Montana</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-thbi-NE" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Nebraska</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-ow68-NM" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">New Mexico</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-wq1q-ND" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">North Dakota</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-qc22-UT" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Utah</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-pdc9-WY" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Wyoming</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="select2-results__option" role="group" aria-label="Central Time Zone">
        <strong class="select2-results__group">Central Time Zone</strong>
        <ul class="select2-results__options select2-results__options--nested">
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-ahw5-AL" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Alabama</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-epw3-AR" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Arkansas</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-djo5-IL" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Illinois</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-48nq-IA" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Iowa</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-z9b8-KS" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Kansas</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-c3qi-KY" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Kentucky</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-bqwz-LA" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Louisiana</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-9iyt-MN" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Minnesota</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-o3cp-MS" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Mississippi</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-v0yz-MO" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Missouri</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-ct81-OK" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Oklahoma</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-dqar-SD" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">South Dakota</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-sh8p-TX" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Texas</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-qqgp-TN" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Tennessee</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-vxqb-WI" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Wisconsin</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="select2-results__option" role="group" aria-label="Eastern Time Zone">
        <strong class="select2-results__group">Eastern Time Zone</strong>
        <ul class="select2-results__options select2-results__options--nested">
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-di6s-CT" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Connecticut</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-o46k-DE" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Delaware</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-t2ij-FL" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Florida</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-m9l2-GA" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Georgia</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-g598-IN" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Indiana</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-7ntg-ME" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Maine</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-onug-MD" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Maryland</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-d2dd-MA" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Massachusetts</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-v85c-MI" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Michigan</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-obw9-NH" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">New Hampshire</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-zzdx-NJ" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">New Jersey</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-7ydt-NY" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">New York</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-8uq8-NC" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">North Carolina</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-7dv9-OH" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Ohio</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-9ofh-PA" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Pennsylvania</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-7lye-RI" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Rhode Island</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-13zm-SC" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">South Carolina</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-3nof-VT" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Vermont</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-wcs2-VA" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Virginia</li>
            <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-x4am-result-9rgp-WV" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">West Virginia</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Una vez que tienes esto ya puedes usar el evento [onScroll](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp) del `ul` si utilizas Javascript *puro* o el evento [scroll](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) de jQuery.
Algo como esto:

```
$("ul.select2-results__options").scroll(function() {
  alert("Se ha hecho scroll!");
});
```

Comment: Creo que sería oportuno para que la respuesta estuviera completa, que pusieras un ejemplo de como controlar esos eventos con ese componente.

Comment: en la web de select2 no veo esa opcion por ningun lado. Si que veo una opcion de cargar opciones dinamicamente en funcion de si se llega una posicion determinada, que al final es lo que quiero hacer, que cuando el usuario se desplace hasta la posicion 50, que cargue 100 opciones mas, y que cuando se desplace a la 100, cargue 100 mas y asi sucesivamente.

Comment: @Quarkbite yo supongo que se refiera a que como `select2` lo que hace es construir un selector propio en html. Puedes recuperar la capa en donde se encuentran las opciones y suscribirte al evento scroll de la misma.

Comment: Editado con un ejemplo de la documentación oficial

Comment: @ManuelRobles Así mucho mejor, no obstante, como la pregunta es concretamente sobre como gestionar el evento en cuestión igual el ejemplo pudiera ser sobre el evento (el que hay está bien, pero no responde a la pregunta). Lo que responde a la pregunta es el enlace que poner, pero sería preferible que además del enlace la solución se encontrase también en la respuesta, de este modo se mejora las búsquedas y posicionamiento de la solución y no queda completamente invalidada si el enlace se rompe o muere.

Comment: @frikinside del código solo es relevante la primera clase que le pone, el resto es "paja" que deje para que se viera como es completo pero no es relevante. Respecto a lo del enlace, solo pone que tienes que añadir "onScroll" a la clase, por lo que no cambiara mucho ponerlo

Comment: @ManuelRobles No debo de estar explicándome apropiadamente. Me refiero a que no hay un ejemplo de código de cómo detectar el `scroll`. Permíteme que añada una edición a la respuesta con un sencillo ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Hice la prueba con `div` con el uso de angular, logre que reconosca el evento '`scroll`' en un `div`, pero cuando lo cambio para `select` no funciona.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {});

app.directive('goScroll', function($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

      elem.on('scroll', function(evt) {
        console.log("moviendome");
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contenido2').scroll(function() {
      var windowHeight = $('#contenido2').scrollTop();
      console.log(windowHeight);
    });
  });
</script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <div>

    <div style="height: 400px; border:solid 1px black; overflow:auto;" go-scroll>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```